# How do you call this kind of functions in english?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have a couple of formulas that I would like to plot, but I can't find the much needed documentation for them because I don't know how to correctly name them in english .

This formulas assume that both $x$ and $y$ are independent variables ( free to vary ) and use basic functions such as the absolute value of something or simple trigonometric functions like $\mathbb{sin(x)}$ or $\mathbb{cos(x)}$; for example :

- $|y|-|x|=tan(y)\times{\frac{-(sin(1/x))}{tan(1/y)}}$ [preview](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cy%7C-%7Cx%7C%3Dtan%28y%29*%28-%28sin%281%2Fx%29%29%2Ftan%281%2Fy%29%29)
- $|x|\times|y|=cos((cos(x) + sin(y))\times acos(x))$ [preview](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%7C%7Cy%7C%3Dcos%28%28cos%28x%29%20%2B%20sin%28y%29%29acos%28x%29%29)

And by the way if you know a software or framework ( in lua, python, ... etc ), that is able to plot this kind of formulas in an interactive way ( where you have a GUI and you can input a formula on the fly ), please suggest one .

Thanks .

Comment: Those aren't functions by the [vertical line test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test).

Comment: @Hakim I'm calling them "formulas", I wrote that they _use_ functions, but since I don't know how to call those, I just call them formulas. I know that there are multiple $y$ for the same $x$ value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call them 'level sets'. Imagine you have a function

$f(x,y) = |y| - |x| - \tan(y)\frac{-\sin(1/x)}{\tan(1/y)}$

then you're looking for the set of points where $f(x,y) = 0$.

In python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np

delta = 0.05
xrange = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, delta)
yrange = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, delta)
x, y = np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)

f = np.absolute(y) - np.absolute(x) - np.tan(y)*(-np.sin(1/x)/np.tan(1/y))

matplotlib.pyplot.contour(x, y, f, [0])
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I'm trying to find some free software that plots this using this _level set_ keyword, but nothing for now, if you have any suggestions, maybe an alternative keyword.

Comment: you might also call it an 'implicit plot'. In either event, there is now some python above that will give you what you want.

Comment: 1 thing, so matplotlib doesn't _compute anything_, it's numpy that computes stuff ?

Comment: yes, `matplotlib` is the visual library, `numpy` is the numerical one.